# Linux CPU Utilization Reporting Tool (Linux CURT)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perf-event

I am trying to use linux curt (https://github.com/open-power-sdk/curt) tool for monitoring CPU utilization values of threads. On running this command '''    perf record -e '{raw_syscalls:*,sched:sched_switch,sched:sched_migrate_task,sched:sched_process_exec,sched:sched_process_fork,sched:sched_process_exit,sched:sched_stat_runtime,sched:sched_stat_wait,sched:sched_stat_sleep,sched:sched_stat_blocked,sched:sched_stat_iowait,powerpc:hcall_entry,powerpc:hcall_exit}' -a *command --args*
''' I am getting following [image] error (my ubuntu distribution is 20.04). even if skip this step. I am getting errors while running ''' perf script -s ./curt.py''' command.[image] please guide me on how to solve this issue?